# Does Karate Support displaying the assertions or failures in the html Report for Server side scenario of incoming API requests to a mock server?

Tags: karate

This might be a dumb question or may be already answered but i wasnt able to find any answers for this :

I have a requirement of testing a Micro Service that sends out an API request to a particular endpoint or a Consumer. I was able to successfully write the mocks using karate and send back response on required filter criteria and validations happening inside the "server-side" scenario.

If any assertion fails it does log that server-side scenario failed.
I wanted to know how i can add these to a report ( i currently use the cucumber reporting which can be integrated with Karate) and fail a test if any server side scenario fails?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question, this is an unusual requirement - but you can be super-creative with Karate mocks.

Remember - a Karate mock is a legitimate REST server, so all you need to do is add one more request "route". You already know that you can "collect" data into global variables defined in the `Background`. So something like this:

```
Background:
* def errors = []

Scenario: pathMatches('/myapi')
* def result = karate.match("request == { foo: 'bar' }")
* if (!result.pass) errors.add(result)
* def response = { some: 'response' }

Scenario: pathMatches('/mytest')
* def response = errors
```

Now at the end of your test, just call the additional `/mytest` API and you get a nice JSON array of all errors.

For those looking for even more complex patterns, for example how to handle a webhook or "callback" refer: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1417023536082812935