# Karate mock additional endpoint for collecting errors returns an empty array

Tags: mocking, karate

I'm using the Karate version 1.2.0. I have some assertions in the mock and I tried to extract errors following answer here:[Does Karate Support displaying the assertions or failures in the html Report for Server side scenario of incoming API requests to a mock server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64779619/does-karate-support-displaying-the-assertions-or-failures-in-the-html-report-for)

I set a global variable:
Background:

- def errors  = []

And my endpoints in mock looks like
Scenario:

```
pathMatches('/services/myService/{id}}') && methodIs('put')
    * def result = karate.match("$request//UpdateRequest/activity == 'wrong_activity'")
    * if (!result.pass) {karate.appendTo(errors, result)}
    * def responseStatus = 200

  Scenario: pathMatches('/mytest')
    * configure responseHeaders = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    * def responseStatus = 200
    * def response = {'errors':'#(errors)'}
```

My test just sends a GET request to

- url 'http://localhost:9866/mytest'

I'm expecting to get an array of errors in my test. But the response has an empty array
[Karate response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TX6QI.jpg)
But if I'm sending the same GET request from Postman, the response contains the array with errors
[Postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKVwe.jpg)
I've tried to change headers, but the result is the same.

Comment: I'm unable to figure this out from reading this q, so hopefully someone else has better ideas. personally I think if you follow this process, that can help others help you: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue