# Need to extract response from XHR API call after I clicked on a button on current web page

Tags: karate

Using Karate DSL, I Need to extract response from XHR API call after I clicked on a button on current web page. PFA screenshot as below. Here I need to get the response from API which comes in XHR after clicked on the button "Complete Your Reservation" on the current page.

You can see "key" as a name appearing in XHR. I need to get value of PaymentKeys as per attached screenshot.
I tried the "driver.intecept()" method as mentioned in the page: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#intercepting-http-requests

- driver.intercept({ patterns: [{ urlPattern: '*hpc.uat.testpay.com*' }], mock: 'mock-01.feature' })

But I am getting error as org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (intercept) on com.intuit.karate.driver.chrome.ChromeWebDriver@5a5c128 failed due to: Unknown identifier: intercept

- .:program(Unnamed:1)

I am using karate DSL version 1.3.0. I mentioned the code as below:

- driver.intercept({ patterns: [{ urlPattern: '*hpc.uat.testpay.com*' }], mock: 'mock-01.feature' })

Please suggest what to do over here.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/125981 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver type should be `chrome` and not `chromedriver` for `driver.intercept()` to work. Please read the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core/#driverintercept

Comment: Thank you so much @Peter Thomas. I am able to calll driver.intercept() method with drivertype as chrome only. 
But I am unable to fetch the XHR request & it's response as per the attached screenshot in first post. 
Can you please let me know how to capture it?

Comment: @JeetendraEdke if the mock was called, you can make a call to the mock to get any data you want. refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64779852/143475

Comment: I have gone through your page https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-core/#driverintercept, section "Intercepting HTTP Requests"
as- We will use this page: https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/dynamic-data-loading-demo.html - as an example. When a button on this page is clicked, a request is made to https://api.randomuser.me/?nat=us - which returns some JSON data.

 Can you please let me know how would you capture the json data return on response.

Comment: @JeetendraEdke actually this may be a gap in karate. I've opened a feature request here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2361 - you are welcome to contribute code or influence someone to do it

Comment: Thanks @Peter Thomas for quick reply again & finally concluded this topic. But I am looking forward to have this feature in karate DSL.