how can i add devtoolsdriver listener in karate
In my case, i want to extract what api will be called after interact with UI. As i know in selenium version 4.x we can use DevTools to add listener like this
devTools = ((HasDevTools) driver).getDevTools();
devTools.createSession();
devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
devTools.addListener(Network.requestWillBeSent(),
   entry -> {
   System.out.println("Request URI : " + entry.getRequest().getUrl()+"\n"
   + " With method : "+entry.getRequest().getMethod() + "\n");
   entry.getRequest().getMethod();
 });
}

In karate, i used driver.method('Network.enable').send() then tried driver.intercept() with mock server then saved request information but i can't continue request like normal, driver().method('Fetch.enable') but nothing can use. Any suggestion in this case ?
I want to extract event like this

I suggest that you don't focus on what selenium does. Is your requirement to get data from an API call that was intercepted ? Then this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76680528/143475

Thanks for your quick response. i just want to extract what API will be called when we click on an element, anyway i solved it by using console to get log entry and also can hack to logger of devtoolsdriver. for now i have a scenario to interactive with camera so i want to modify the request body with right image before it be sent. Can we do that ?

@TuấnAnhTrần I don't know for sure. I suggest you read the docs and figure it out
